# Global install of Adobe XD

Tags: deployment, adobe

I am attempting to install Adobe Creative Cloud on my client computers using an installation package created using Adobe's Admin Console.  Everything works except for Adobe XD, which is only installed for the administrative user account that ran the package, not for the end users.

How can I do a global installation of Adobe XD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (sort of) answered in [Deploying Adobe XD for Enterprise: Issues and Limitations](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/enterprise/kb/deploy-adobe-xd-known-issues.html):

> Adobe XD package installation, when done locally, makes Adobe XD available only for the user account that the installation was performed under.
>
> Adobe recommends that you to deploy Adobe XD in a logged off machine state. This ensures that Adobe XD is made available to any user who logs into the machine.

That's about as clear as mud, but the most obvious guess turned out to be the correct one: you need to run the install package as local system in order to make Adobe XD available to all users.

Comment: Could you please more explain, how install package as local system?

Comment: I tried installing Adobe XD 55.2.12 with the command `PsExec64 -s -i Set-up.exe` ([PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)) from an elevated shell (when I'm logged in as an administrator), but this ends with an obscure error message like `C:\...\Set-up.exe exited on PC??????? with error code -1073741819` (the code `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005`, which is an _access denied error_). See also [user request](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests-read-only/suggestions/37935421-make-installation-via-system-account-windows-10).